# Put quotes around string before first forward slash in line by line file read

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

I am writing a bash script that deletes all the files whose paths are given in `delete.txt`. `delete.txt` is thousands of lines long, each line has a path that is structured like this:

```
Abies concolor/images/FV-GFVM-725_crop.jpg
```

Where there is a space in the name of the first directory.

Currently, my bash script reads each line of delete.txt, saves it to`$line` and deletes it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    "rm $line"
done < "$1"
```

However, because there is a space in the first directory name, my rm command returns:

```
rm Abies concolor/images/FV-GFVM-725_crop.jpg: No such file or directory
```

What can I do in my bash script to add a quote before the first and after the second words of each line before doing the rm command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `rm` invocation. Just correctly quote `line` variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   rm "$line"
done < "$1"
```

Or, even simpler, you can use [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and this oneliner which replaces the complete script:

```
cat delete.txt | xargs -I{} rm '{}'
```

This will run `rm` for each line in `delete.txt`, properly quoted. The trick here is to use `-I <placeholder>` option which will make sure the command `rm '<placeholder>'` is executed once per line (not word), each time substituting `<placeholder>` with filename from current line.